# How to export feed agregator list and setting as feature?

Tags: features, feeds

I want to export feed aggregator list and settings as feature. If both aggregator list and settings cannot be exported, then how to export? Thanks a lot.

Comment: is this the agregator from core ? i guess you will have to resort to feeds - much more flexibility and exportability :)

Answer (score 4):

I have achieved this using [`aggregator_save_feed()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!aggregator!aggregator.module/function/aggregator_save_feed/7) function in [`hook_install()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_install/7) or [`hook_update_N()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7) of my custom module. It's not a feature but there is not much difference.

Example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function MYMODULE_install() {
  $feed = array(
    'title' => 'Business',
    'url' => 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/business/rss.xml',
    'refresh' => 3600, // Update interval in seconds
    'block' => 5, // News items in block
  );
  aggregator_save_feed($feed);
}
```